# Storing maps of children in vector of base class

Tags: c++, vector, maps

I am currently trying to store multiple maps of `<int, Derived>` in a vector of the base class.

Example:

```
std::map<int, Derived_1 *> map_1 = smth;
std::map<int, Derived_2 *> map_2 = smth_else;

std::vector<std::map<int, Base *>> list;

list.push_back(map_1);
list.push_back(map_2);
```

However, when compiling I get the error that there is no conversion between the derived map and the base class.

Is there a better (or simply working) way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would let you do `list[0][0] = new Derived_2;` even though `list[0]` is a `std::map<int, Derived_1 *>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to achieve it directly, since `std::map<int, Base*>` and `std::map<int, Derived_1*>` are different types.

The most straightforward solution is to use `std::map<int, Base*>` everywhere instead. Another one would be to make a conversion function, but it's less elegant and you'll incur in performance penalties.

Another option, although more limited, would be to use a [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (if using C++17), or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant.html), to store all posible types. The counterpart is that you'll probably have to deal with visitors and so on.

Comment: Asking dumb questions here, but then i would have to cast to my derived type everytime that i use it, right?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. On the other hand, if you are using a class hierarchy is because probably derived classes implement (override) some specific behaviour of base class, and in such case you just call the base's virtual functions. This is called [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) (probably you already knew it, just to be clear here).

Comment: On the other hand, if each derived class have a different interface, then I'd suggest to review your design (or to use variants).